# Retrieving well formed HTML using Jericho HTML parser in Java

Tags: java, html

I've looked at jTidy for converting a snipped of malformed/real-world HTML into well-formed HTML/XHTML. However, there's a bug in the latest version due to which I'm not able to use it. I'm looking at Jericho since it has a lot of positive reviews around the net.

However, its not immediately obvious to me how one would go about implementing a method like:

`public String getValidHTML(String messedUpHTML)`

For instance, if it was passed `<div>bar`, it would return `<div>bar</div>`

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jericho's HTMLSanitiser sample](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/HTMLSanitiser.java) might be a good start.

However, keep in mind that jericho's key strength is its ability to parse and manipulate malformed HTML, while **keeping** the original "bad" formatting. However, it'd be interesting to see how the library performs such a task.

Comment: Thanks. I'll start off with this. Though I think this will be painful.